# OpenShift Jenkins git clone fails: Host key verification failed

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, openshift

I try to build my Node JS (latest version) application in Jenkins in the Red Hat OpenShift environment but it continues to fail with this message in the Jenkins log:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Upon further investigation it turns out the Jenkins server cannot clone the repo from the application server:

```
[JENKINS_HOST test]\> git clone ssh://GUID@APP_HOST/~/git/sof.git
    Cloning into 'sof'...
    The authenticity of host 'APP_HOST (172.16.6.220)' can't be established.
    RSA key fingerprint is cf:ee:77:cb:0e:fc:02:d7:72:7e:ae:80:c0:90:88:a7.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
    Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts  (/var/lib/openshift/GUID/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I cannot even enter the `.ssh` directory on the Jenkins host.

Take it the OpenShift app management should handle all the private keys between the app and the CI host but doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?
I've searched all over the web but OpenShift-specific scenarios are not common.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with custom cartridge https://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smerrill/openshift-community-git-ssh
The cartridge creates script and sets the GIT_SSH environment variable to run git-ssh without strict host key checking.

So,

1. Install the cartridge with your Openshift web-console to your jenkins application (Applications / jenkins / "Or, see the entire list of cartridges you can add", put the link into "Install your own cartridge" field)
2. Connect to jenkins application via ssh: ssh @jenkins-.rhcloud.com
3. cd ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/git-ssh/
4. ssh-keygen
   4.1. Set key file ./id_rsa
   4.2. Leave password empty
   This creates files id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/git-ssh/ directory
5. Print your id_rsa.pub: cat id_rsa.pub
6. Copy the contents of id_rsa.pub
7. In Openshift web console go to Settings, add new public key
8. Fill key name and paste the contents of id_rsa.pub into second field, press "Create"
9. Restart jenkins application

Now git clone must be ok

Comment: Hi Oleg, tried your recipe but arrived at the same error:
`Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/openshift/571545187628e1fc39000022/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/openshift/571545187628e1fc39000022/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: Sorry for being offline for a long time. What is the value of your GIT_SSH environment variable? (Connect to application via ssh, call "echo $GIT_SSH".) It seems the cartridge has not been installed correctly.

Comment: Hi Oleg, this is the output of that command: `/var/lib/openshift/571545187628e1fc39000022/gitssh/usr/bin/git-ssh`

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. Although I used another fork: https://github.com/damaestro/openshift-community-git-ssh

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to commit change the [protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) to `http` and you will not need to use ssh keys since it should be read-only if your server allow you and support this protocol.

If you must use ssh they you must set-up the ssh keys. No way to "skip" it.

Comment: Do you know how to 'reset' all the ssh keys using the rhc tool? And how to deploy them to the relevant hosts?

Comment: But you can't skip the step of installing ssh keys unless you change the clone url.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works with SSH. I try to ssh into from the Jenkins box into the one that has the repo and I get the same error. I cannot physically add the keys on either of the boxes because I cannot access the ~/,ssh directory. This setup is really weird. How can anyone work with Node.js proejct in Openshift if you can't do basic stuff like CI using Jenkins that they provide? Really thinking of going elsewhere for a hosted Node.js solution. I cannot find anything in their help files, tried re-creating the application from scratch (both the target app and Jenkins) with no results.

Comment: You must have access to the machine to do it. The workaround it to use the http/https protocol and set the username/password in the credentials section under the git clone url

Answer (score 0):

if anyone gets here and he just can't get his private repo to be cloned on openshift. Not with SSH and not with HTTP. Iv'e got a simple solution that works great. Clone with http and add your token to the repo link e.g.

```
git clone https://<token>@github.com/owner/repo.git
```